# Promise pending when I try to pass API call from one component to another as a prop

Tags: reactjs, promise, components

I am working on a large project and from examples within the project I've found some components pass API calls from one component to another as a prop. However they mostly do it using class components and not using hooks. I am more familiar with using hooks and functional components. Here I am working with two components one that is a class component and one that is a functional component Im building from scratch. I am trying to make the api call in the parent component :

```
class ProviderDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { unsignedNote: true };
    this.toggle = () =>
      this.setState({ unsignedNote: false });
  }

return (
      <div>
        {this.state.unsignedNote &&
        <UnsignedNoteModal 
      onSubmit={this.toggle}
      getList={api.Encounters.unsignedEncounters}
      />}
        <NavBar />
        <div className="dashboard-container">
          <h4>
            {" "}
            <div className="header-icon float-left">
              <DashboardIcon />
            </div>{" "}
            Dashboard{" "}
          </h4>
 </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ProviderDashboard);
```

When I try to pass the `getList` and console.log it I get something that looks like this in my console. `ƒ unsignedEncounters() { return requests.get("/provider-encounters/unsigned-encounters"); }`
However if I pass the api call like this
`getList={api.Encounters.unsignedEncounters(e => e)}`
I get a promise fulfilled object with the response Im looking for buried in a bunch of functions in the console. Can someone explain what Im missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `api.Encounters.unsignedEncounters` is a function which returns a promise.

If you want the child component to be responsible for calling the api function:

```
const UnsignedNoteModal = ({ getList }) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getList().then(setList);
    // or depending on the data shape getList.then(r => setList(r?.data?.something));
  }, []);

  // Some jsx that uses list
};
```

> I am trying to make the api call in the parent component

In that case, do exactly the same thing but with `setState` instead of `setList`. Or do a little refactor and make your parent a functional component too.

```
const ProviderDashboard = () => {
  const [unsignedNote, setUnsignedNote] = useState(true);
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const mapState = useSelector(mapStateToProps);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    api.Encounters.unsignedEncounters()
      .then(setList);
  });

  const toggle = () => setUnsignedNote(!unsignedNote);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        unsignedNote &&
        <UnsignedNoteModal
          onSubmit={toggle}
          // Or just list={list}
          getList={() => list}
        />
      }
      < NavBar />
      <div className="dashboard-container">
        <h4>
          {" "}
          <div className="header-icon float-left">
            <DashboardIcon />
          </div>{" "}
          Dashboard{" "}
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div >
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your solution works when I try send the prop as `{api.Encounters.unsignedEncounters(e => e)}`

Comment: It would help if you tell us the signature of `api.Encounters.unsignedEncounters`. You are passing a lambda as a parameter and returning a promise, but it looks like the function is actually parameterless.

Comment: Oh, it's because I made a mistake and wrote it as `getList.then(...)`. Which makes sense because that syntax would require the prop to be a promise. It should actually be `getList().then(...)`